# Apple EarPods buzzing except when I'm touching the area around the MacBook Trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones

I've been using the Apple EarPods with my MacBook Air for a while now. Since recently, they have been producing a very faint buzzing in the left earbud when I'm not touching the computer.

However, when I touch the areas around the keyboard, Trackpad, and screen bezel, the buzzing stops. But as soon as I take my hand off the aluminium unibody or the bezel, it starts buzzing again. Even if I touch the body very lightly, such as the very tip of my finger, it stops.

That being said, what's happening and how do I stop the buzzing in that ear altogether?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you observing the buzzing when your MacBook is connected to a power source? What is your observation when you disconnect the power source and run the MacBook on battery?

Comment: When I run the computer on battery the buzzing stops. What should I do about this instance?

Comment: Please see the [answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360348/279727).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your MacBook isn't properly grounded. This probably explains the buzzing sound that you are hearing.

When you are touching the aluminium surface of your MacBook, you are technically creating a way for the charge to move, technically providing the grounding, which explains why the buzzing stops.

It is recommended to use the adapter with a three pin extension cord. When using it, your MacBook gets grounded, preventing any change from staying and generating the buzzing sound.